# Angular Routing Login module unexpected directive imported [ERROR]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am having this error specifically;

```
Unexpected directive 'LoginComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

does anyone know what it is for? my app-routing.module is as such;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './components/login/login.component#LoginModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and app.module is as

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    OverlayModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LoginComponent,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

my login.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onLogin() {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }
}
```

where's the grief exactly? can anyone give me a hint in the right direction? `AppModule` contains my `LoginComponent` inside the `imports` section as expected. Then why the above error? Could you please explain? My app is expected to load the login page upon launch, ie. `localhost:4200` should basically load the login just as `localhost:4200/login` also should.

Not very clear to me what I did wrong logically here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `LoginComponent` from `imports` and add it to `declarations`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    OverlayModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

`imports` is used for importing other modules and make their functionality available to current module. components are not imported to a module in angular, modules are. components are declared as part of a module.

Comment: hey @ysf  let me try out this edit. I will revert back,

Comment: hi @ysf   it works, like you had pointed out. understanding problem on my part, of the component inclusion concept, nothing to do with routing;